# How to execute a function inside a python script?

Tags: python-3.x, bash

How can I execute the below simple script called `foo.py` from the (bash) command line?

```
def hello():
    return 'Hi :)'
```

I tried the following and got an error.

```
 $ python -c 'import foo; print foo.hello()'

  File "<string>", line 1
    import foo; print foo.hello()
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I'm able to execute the following but just receive no output.

```
$ python foo.py
$
```

Comment: Use ```python foo.py``` this is correct.
You didn't receive an output because you didn't call the function, you just defined it.
def hello():
    return 'Hi :)'
print hello()

Comment: Try python -c "import foo; print(foo.hello())"

Comment: @AhsanGoheer I get a greater than sign.  `$ python -c "import foo; print(foo.hello())`
`>`

Comment: @jgg you get the greater than sign as an output?

Comment: @AhsanGoheer Yes I got the greater than sign.  I think it was because of the double quotes.  Once I changed to single quotes it worked.

Comment: Oh! Must be an OS thing. It worked on windows for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print foo.hello()
```

Is this Python2?

remove that `print` before function call:

```
$ python -c 'import foo; foo.hello()'
```

Or make it like python3 syntax:

```
$ python -c 'import foo; print(foo.hello())'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using python 2.x, use:

```
import foo; print foo.hello()
```

However, on python 3.x brackets are required:

```
import foo; print(foo.hello())
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe your Python version is 3.x

On Python3 print should have "()"

you can try

```
print(foo.hello())
```